# Need assist with a simple PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with php basic syntax, I'm really new to the language.
I'm trying to fetch data from MySQL, as you can see, 1 table 6 columns and 2 rows.

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+
| first| second | third  | fourth | fifth | sixth|
+------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+
|  A1  |   B1   |   C1   |   D1   |   E1  |  F1  |
|  A2  |   B2   |   C2   |   D2   |   E2  |  F2  |
+------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+
```

my php file code

```
<?php
define('HOST','irrelevant');
define('USERNAME','irrelevant');
define('PASSWORD','irrelevant');
define('DB','irrelevant');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB) or die('Unable to connect');

$sql = "select * from orders";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
//array_push($result,array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5]));
//}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

All I need here is this output which is 1 array with a count(array)=2 :P

{A1 
 B1 
 C1 
 D1 
 E1 
 F1 , A2 
 B2 
 C2 
 D2 
 E2 
 F2}

without the <'br'> command between them all it should look like this

{A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1 , A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2}

in other words, I need it to turn into an array that has just 2 strings in it (the number of rows that currently exist in the table).

This is probably very easy to someone who knows php good, if id'e need to implement this in java it would take me a minute but, damn this php and all these dollars!

thanks in advance

Comment: Is the code you already have giving any errors?

Comment: the php code is just fetching the values from the database which I also added as a comment becuase I dont know if its even smart to fetch them straight away to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching the data into an array (as you currently are doing it) isn't a problem, but it seems like you're adding each value into it's own element in the array, instead of the whole row into one element.

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result, $row[0]." ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]." ".$row[3]." ".$row[4]." ".$row[5]);
}
```

This will make `$result[0]` have the values `A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1` and `$result[1]` have the values `A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2`. If you had used a comma as a separator, you would not put it all into `$result` as one element, but every `$row` as an element of its own.

Comment: PHP genius!   thank you man!  and thanks to the other 2 guys who tried to help, I must accept the working solution

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, you just needed to append all your results to an array:

```
<?php
define('HOST','irrelevant');
define('USERNAME','irrelevant');
define('PASSWORD','irrelevant');
define('DB','irrelevant');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB) or die('Unable to connect');

$sql = "select * from orders";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  array_push($result,array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5]));
}

var_dump($result);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Hey blaze, thanks for the reply, I was shocked at first to see the output :D

Comment: but I need not just an output but an actual new array with 2 strings in it :(

Comment: lol, I like `var_dump()`. Some people don't, but I prefer to see what is happening while I debug my code. Could you please reply with the output that was displayed onscreen with my var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result[$i], array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5]));
      $i++;
}
```

Count array:

```
echo count($result); // will write 2 (rows)
echo count($result[0]); // will write 6 (columns)
```

If you want only an array with 2 strings, you could try this:

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result[$i], ($row[0] . '  ' .  $row[1] . '  ' . $row[2] . '  ' . $row[3] . '  ' . $row[4] . '  ' . $row[5]));
      $i++;
}
```

If you don't want spaces, just remove (`. '  '`). Example:

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result[$i], ($row[0] .  $row[1] . $row[2] . $row[3] . $row[4]  . $row[5]));
      $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hey allan, also, thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it, thing is, I'm not looking for the output I'm looking for the array it self, the actual one with 2 strings in it  {A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1, A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2}

Comment: I edited my answer to put result in an array with 2 strings.

Comment: Hey man, thanks again , once I get this done my project is done , sadly I got this error 
( ! ) Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\test4.php on line 22
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 244528 {main}( ) ..\test4.php:0
2 0.0000 259240 array_push ( ) ..\test4.php:22

( ! ) Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\test4.php on line 22
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 244528 {main}( ) ..\test4.php:0
2 0.0000 260144 array_push ( ) ..\test4.php:22
Array ( [0] => [1] => )

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB) or       die('Unable to connect');

    $sql = "select * from orders";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $result = array();


$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result[$i], ($row[0].'  '.$row[1].'  '.$row[2].'  '.$row[3].'  '.$row[4].'  '.$row[5]));
      $i++;
}


print_r($result);

mysqli_close($con);

?>

Comment: dunno how to make that a code on reply :/     thats the full code , maybe I'm not printing output right?